# use sql and print the values from two different tables in the result

Tags: sql

I have three tables namely, user, roles, performer_owner. I wrote the following query to extract the users who have roles 6(i.e performer)

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid in (select uid from `users_roles` where rid= 6 )
```

Now I will get all the columns in users table if I use the above sql query. Along with that from the third table performer_owner I want a column named `entity_id`. `entity_id` is the owner's id. The performer's id in that is `field_performer_owner_id` for which I will get data from the above sql query in the form of `uid`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join,

```
select
         u.*,
         po.entity_id
from `users` u
join `performer_owner` po on po.field_performer_owner_id = u.id
where u.uid in (select uid from `users_roles` where rid= 6);
```